# Native mobile Dapp - Sign transactions with user wallet

Tags: metamask, dapp-design, mobile-wallet

I'm starting a new project that involves a mobile Dapp and I have a question regarding signing transactions.

Every mobile Dapp post that I read about offered two solutions:

- Use a Dapp browser, such as Status or Trust, or
- Develop a wallet inside the app

The first solution involves developing for browsers, less features and the experience is not the same. And the second forces the user to use another account (I get that accounts are free, but come on I don't want another one, transfer from my wallet to start, save the seed, etc.).

I guess that I could allow to use the mnemonic but that is also a pain in the bottom.

My question is simple, is it possible for users to use their own wallet (assuming they have it on the same phone) to sign transactions of my Dapp? If users have already Toshi/Coinbase, Status, Trust, is there any way they can use it to sign transactions from my Dapp?

Maybe I'm too biased with Metamask, but I think it would be great to be using a mobile Dapp, and when I want to call a smart-contract, that my wallet (i.e: coinbase) would pop-up and show my what I'm about to do and confirm it.

Anyway, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is on the roadmap for a number of dapp wallets, where an SDK will allow the exact behaviour you're looking for - opens their wallet, signs/sends, then calls back to your app.

However currently no wallet provides this feature unfortunately. You'll either need to use the solutions you already mentioned, or look into [meta transactions](https://medium.com/@austin_48503/ethereum-meta-transactions-90ccf0859e84) ([Universal Logins](https://universallogin.io/) look promising).

Answer (score 0):

Hi dear im fancing the same problem , i olso think that create new wallet on the board of the app is not so user frendly or let them import theyr keystore.
The solution i found but cannot make it work its wallet connect solution .
You insert wallet connect module on you android dapp and then they can chose mobile and then chose one of theyr preferit wallets like metamask ,raibow etc.
Or web3modal is olso a good solution .